# How to set the length of the low band-pass filter (seconds) when filtering EEG?

Tags: pac, bandpass-filter

When I used the `neurodsp` model to compute the Phase-Amplitude coupling of EEG, I found there are four parameters need to set carefully, respectively `N_seconds_lo`, `N_seconds_hi`, `N_cycles_pha` and `N_cycles_amp`. The results were very different when the four parameters changed. I searched some documents but could not find related formula or setting methods. How to set the four parameters? The `neurodsp` model link is :

https://github.com/voytekresearch/neurodsp/blob/master/neurodsp/pac.py